# Why does type class coverage condition fail in Haskell but not PureScript

Tags: haskell, purescript

I have two implementations of what I believe to be equivalent type class and instance definitions. The PureScript version builds without error but the Haskell version fails with the error `Un-determined variables: e, f`.

Can I make this work in Haskell?

**Haskell:**

```hs
class Foo a b c | a b -> c where
newtype Bar a b = Bar (a, b)
instance (Foo a c e, Foo b d f) => Foo (Bar a b) (Bar c d) (Bar e f) where
```

**PureScript:**

```
class Foo a b c | a b -> c
newtype Bar a b = Bar (Tuple a b)
instance (Foo a c e, Foo b d f) => Foo (Bar a b) (Bar c d) (Bar e f)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must enable `UndecidableInstances`; then your declaration will work. It's a bit subtle why this is required, i.e. how *not* enabling it could lead to a loop in the type-checker. But suppose in your program, you somehow caused the following constraint to need to be solved:

```
Foo (Bar a b) (Bar c d) a
```

The constraint solver would happily observe that we must choose the instance you wrote, and decide that therefore `a ~ Bar a0 a1` for some `a0` and `a1`, meaning we would like to solve the constraint:

```
Foo (Bar (Bar a0 a1) b) (Bar c d) (Bar a0 a1)
```

Now we can dispatch to the context, meaning we now need to solve the following two constraints:

```
( Foo (Bar a0 a1) c a0
, Foo b d a1
)
```

But wait! That first constraint is in the same form as the constraint we started with, but with different type variables. A loop!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, so PureScript allows undecidable instances by default?

Comment: @tom Dunno, I've never used PureScript. Perhaps an actual expert can answer that for you.

Comment: PureScript does indeed work similarly to `UndecidableInstances`. In Haskell, with UI enabled, the termination check is deferred to the use site, at which point trying to solve a looping constraint would produce an error saying "_Reduction stack overflow_". In PureScript, the same attempt results in error "_Type class instance for (blah) is possibly infinite_". I must admit, I don't know for sure how the PS compiler determines that: whether it just tries and sees if it loops for long enough (like GHC does) or there is a more clever way.